# Scraping Reviews from yelp always returns first page

Tags: python, yelp

To preface I'm new to python so maybe I'm overlooking something simple.

The url pattern for yelp goes something like

```
'URL'?start=X
```

Where X is representing the reviews the previous page ended on.  So if the previous page was 10 X would be 10.
My first question is why does it return 20 values when using `requests.get`

Ex url: `https://www.yelp.com/biz/moto-i-ramen-and-sake-house-minneapolis-2?start=`

My second question is why does my program return the same values each iteration of a loop. Each time I run the program it returns the first page of reviews on yelp. Even If I just to try to use the URL outside of my loop `https://www.yelp.com/biz/moto-i-ramen-and-sake-house-minneapolis-2?start=20` even if I try to use a url like this outside of the loop it still returns the same 20 reviews.

```
for x in url_list:
response = requests.get(base_url+str(x*19+x), headers=headers)
text = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
file = str(text.findAll('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'})[1])
file2 = str(file.strip()[35:-9])
data = json.loads(file2)
print(data)
```

Theres 5 items in url_list. and Base_url is similar to the example

Comment: May I ask the precise contents of `url_list`, and `base_url`

Comment: and url+list would be 
`['https://www.yelp.com/biz/house-of-wong-roseville?start=0', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/house-of-wong-roseville?start=20', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/house-of-wong-roseville?start=40', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/house-of-wong-roseville?start=60', 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/house-of-wong-roseville?start=80']`

base_url would be
`'https://www.yelp.com/biz/house-of-wong-roseville?start='`

im beginning to think it's something to do with yelp's antiscrape